# Firebase web storage list API get item name

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am successfully getting a list of items from a cloud storage directory as per below, but I cannot work out how to get the names of the items. For example, if "my_dir2" contains the files "myfile1.txt" and "myfile2.txt", I would like these file names printed out.

```
const storage = firebase.storage();
const storageRef = storage.ref();
storageRef
  .child("my_dir1/mydir_2")
  .listAll()
  .then(res => {
    res.items.forEach(item => console.log(item)); // I tried item.name() but "name is not a function"
  });
```

Comment: what do you see in the console?

Comment: The code I've given works fine, but I want to get the item name, I've tried item.name() which errors with: "name is not a function"

Comment: your current code doesn't specify name.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out that name is a getter method so doesn't need parenthesis:

```js
const storage = firebase.storage();
const storageRef = storage.ref();
storageRef
  .child("my_dir1/mydir_2")
  .listAll()
  .then(res => {
    res.items.forEach(item => console.log(item.name));
  });
```